# Very simple After Effects expression returns 'undefined value used in expression' error

Tags: javascript, expression, after-effects

Somehow this tried and true expression doesn't work for me anymore.

I'm using it on the position of a Null but it returns an error on the first line that states 'undefined value used in expression':

```
x = time * 66;
[x[0],value[1]]
```

What am I doing wrong? Expressions don't get much simpler than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like this

```
x = time * 66;
[x,value[1]]
```